# Create TypeConverter for two properties in user control?

Tags: c#, components, typeconverter

I have these classes

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public ColumnInfo[] ColumnInfos { get; set; }
    public TableInfo[] TableInfos { get; set; }
}

public class ColumnInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public string Table { get; set; }
}

public class TableInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(Alias) ? Name : Alias;
    }
}
```

How can I display dropDown for ColumnInfo[].Table in design mode that contain TableInfos?

Comment: I create StringListConverter:TypeConverter and used it in ColumnInfo.Table but MyUserControl is not accessible in StringListConverter:TypeConverter to retrieve TableInfo[] because context.Instance return ColumnInfo

Comment: No one have a solution? 
Please suggest another way for this approach.